# PHP Logout won't work online

Tags: php, sql, session, logout

I tried to look my problem up on the internet and on stack overflow, but didn't find an answer that solved my problem. So I have a back-end system for a website I'm creating for an opensource project. I have now just finished transferring everything over to my online domain and database. After a lot of other problem solving, it works now, except for the logging out.

In my back-end header I have the *following url*:

```
<a href="logout.php"><h1>Logout</h1></a>
```

The content of the *logout.php page* is the following:

```
<?php
session_regenerate_id();
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Offline, via MAMP this works without any problem. However online it doesn't destroy my session. I can still access all my session variables, which enables me to stay logged in. As I said before, I tried to look for an answer, but I don't seem to find one that fixes my problem. If anyone has a clue what might be wrong, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
This is how I check on every back-end page, wether or not I'm logged in:

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.   
    session_start(); // Start the php session
}
```

*As you see, **@paulprogrammer**, I do something with cookies. How do I destroy it for sure when I logout?*

**edit(2):**

Ok Thanks paulprogrammer for the pointer. I removed the cookie part from my login check function and turned it onto the following simple function:

```
function sec_session_start() {
session_start();
}
```

This doesn't create a cookie and now it does work. I tried to unset the cookie via the stuff the official php manul said @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php but that didn't do it. So that's why I moved to something simpler that works. As not many people besides me are gonna use the back-end and as it seems to work ok, even without cookies, I call it done. This topic can be closed :)

**final edit(3):**
Ok Thanks to **@paulprogrammer* it works now with cookies as well. Now that I know the answer, it only seems logical that you have to do that. Stupid of me. OK so apparently I had to set the name of the session, just like i did in my session. I do this in the beginning, before i start it. The new, updated, code of the log in check function:

```
<?php
session_name('sec_session_id');
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), '', 100);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();

header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: Any chance you're looking at **cookie** values, and not **session** values?

Comment: @PauProgrammer I think you might be in the correct direction. Check my edit of my original post for an update.

Comment: Try executing `session_name($session_name);` in your logout script too, otherwise PHP will destroy the default session cookie only.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer that works too together with my code from edit 1! Great I'm now using that solution. Thanks mate. I'll put it in a final edit 3.

Comment: Glad it worked Glen.  Added this discussion as an answer, so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the session name in your setup code, but failed to set it in the teardown code. So, during teardown PHP was destroying the default session name, not your custom session name.  The custom session name is still available on the request after logout.

Simply use the `session_name()` function consistently anywhere session operations are being used to ensure the session management is always acting on the correct session token.

In your logout.php:

```
<?php
session_name('sec_session_id');

session_regenerate_id();
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

header("Location: login.php");
?>
```